# Left and Right Mouse click event for a cell in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, mouseevent

I am trying to get an event where if you left click a cell in a `DataGridView`, the contents of that cell will go into a `Textbox`. The same goes if you right click a cell in a `DataGridView` the contents will go into a different `Textbox`. Here is the code I have so far

```
  private void dataGridView2_mirror_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (MouseButtons)
        {
            case MouseButtons.Left:
                textBox3.Text = dataGridView2_mirror.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
                break;

            case MouseButtons.Right:
                textBox4.Text = dataGridView2_mirror.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
```

The problem that I am getting is that it is not recognizing that the cell is being clicked, where as if I put the code into a regular `MouseEventArgs` for mouse down the code will recognize whether it is a right click or a left click.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this idea below. Also i think it's better to use CellMouseUp or CellMouseDown event.

```
private void dataGridView2_mirror_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left))
            {
                textBox3.Text = dataGridView2_mirror.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
                return;
            }

            if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Right))
            {
                textBox4.Text = dataGridView2_mirror.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad I could help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not testing the current button value but the enumeration **itself** which is the same as `if (1 == 1)`.. ((Or to be precise: `None == some integer`))

The minumum fix would be to change to

```
switch (e.Button)
```

But: The [MouseButtons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mousebuttons(v=vs.110).aspx) are a flag enumeration, which means more than one value can be true. Get into the habit of testing just the flag you actually want and always test them like this:

```
e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left)..
```

This makes using a `switch` hard but, as so often and with only two buttons to discern `switch` makes little sense anyway..